# getting date in certain format using $date in MongoDB gives invalid date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

im receiving a document from another service using api and one of the date fields looks like this:

```
    "workloadCreationDate": {
        "$date": 1671580800000
    },
```

but when insert this to the db I get this:

[image]

which is so weird cause nothing really changed in this service so I don't know why suddenly I get invalid date

thanks

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: `$date` requires a `Long` value. In newer version of Node/mongosh the `Long()` constructor requires a **string** parameter, see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/reference/data-types/#long